# Swift3 iOS set UITextView height when line break happens

Tags: ios, swift3, autolayout, uitextview, line-breaks

To make my textView resize its height with the content, i use the following code:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
    self.textViewHeight.constant = contentSize.height

    //textViewHeight is the height constraint of the textView defined in the storyboard.

    return true
}
```

The problem is that it does recognize a change in size when a line break happens. If you press return, it will not resize until you add another character. The same happens if you write enough text for it to make a line break. It will only resize after you put in another character. The same happens when you delete a character to remove a line, you will have to remove another character to resize the height. I feel this looks sloppy since iMessage and Whatsapp do not share this behavior when you write your messages.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following Code:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
var newFrame = textView.frame
newFrame.size = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(fmaxf(Float(newSize.width), Float(fixedWidth))), height: newSize.height)
self.textViewHeight.constant = newSize.height
}
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: thank you for helping, but it still behaves like described :/

Comment: Please check out the updated Answer this is the code I use in my project. Copy the entire function. It will definitely work as desired. Try printing the newFrame value as you break a line.

Comment: Thank you this works! I had to disable scrolling. Do you know a way to achieve this with scrolling enabled?

Comment: See the way I do it is I allow the textView to grow to contain 6 lines of text. During this time the scroll is disabled. After the textView grows above this I enable scrolling and the textView height remains unchanged.

Comment: Here is the condition if (newSize.height >= 40 && newSize.height <= 100)
        {
            self.textViewHeight.constant = newSize.height
            self.viewHeight.constant = newSize.height + 10.0
        }
        if (newSize.height >= 100)
        {
            self.textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }